# click on header gridview

Tags: c#

I have a desktop application which display the data in Datagridview but while click on header of Datagridview this error is shown :- 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
     auto select first row in grid why is autoselection occur No sorting occur.how sorting is possible.Please help me to get out of this error.I am be very thankfull to you.

```
  private void GV_investigate_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int oid = int.Parse(GV_investigate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    }
 private void GV_investigate_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GV_investigate.ClearSelection();

    }
```

Comment: we can only guess from this message but can't help you alot So can please share your code.

Comment: please edit your question with the code triggered by the sort/header click, visual studio will show you an exception thrown from the code somewhere when you reproduce this error in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

before you access to the first position in an array/collection you should verify if the array/collection actually contains at least one element, so something like:

```
if(GV_investigate.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
  int oid = int.Parse(GV_investigate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thnx but why autoselect the first row in grid

Comment: why or how ? what do you mean?

Comment: while click on header of Datagridview they auto select the first row in Datagridview.my concern is how to get overcome the problem of auto select of first row in Datagridview